# NiMH battery charging rate vs life

Tags: battery-charging, nimh

I'm looking at the product info of a NiMH AA battery brand. It says these batteries last up to 2100 recharges while charged as per IEC 61951-2 2011, but they last for only 600 times if recharged using 2017 version of the same standard.

[image: eneloop battery recharge rates vs life]

Does anyone know

1. The charging rate/algorithm specified in the IEC's 2011 standard?
2. What changed in 2017 version?

The standard is behind a paywall. There's a Indian standard *identical* to the 2011 edition available to read [here](https://ia600901.us.archive.org/10/items/gov.in.is.16048.2.2013/is.16048.2.2013.pdf). It mandates charging at \$0,1 I_{t} A\$ prior to tests. (Does it mean 1mA constant current?)

I'm curious because of the dramatic change in the life of the battery with respect to changes in charging. I've gone through other posts here on NiMH charging, this aspect doesn't seem to be covered.

Comment: Changes suggest misleading lifespan caused change in test.  https://standards.iteh.ai/catalog/standards/clc/924645af-d9b9-4616-9dbb-5e54c129172a/en-61951-2-2017-pra1-2021

Comment: Several years ago I was involved in a trial of various brands of AA NiMH cells.  I built a rig that would charge the cells at C/3 and then discharge them at C/3 repeatedly.  After a month the cells were charged at C/10 and the capacities were checked discharging at C/10.  Astonishingly, some of the cells were found to store more than their nominal capacity.  My interpretation of this is that NiMH perform much better in constant use than if left idle, so predicting life in terms of cycles isn’t realistic in most real-world situations

Comment: "up to" is a worthless spec. What's the guaranteed minimum?

Comment: So these numbers are essentially useless?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\$0,1I_tA ~ means~ 0,1I_t [A]\$ which means 10% of the one hour [Ah] capacity rating. But they indicate for NiMH the standard rating is a 5 hr duration, defined as \$C_5\$.  Li Ion & LiPo cells and other batteries usually use \$C_{20}\$ for ratings.

The longer period of charge and discharge reduces temperature rise and degradation.

If the \$C_5\$ rating was 1 [Ah] in 5 hrs then that was rated using 0.2A for  5 h  However, (If I get this right) a test of 0,1It [A] is 10% of the \$C_5\$ capacity converted to one (1) hr or \$0,1~I_t=100 mA\$.

or (0.1 It=0.1A for C5=1Ah)  In the Lithium battery world, I believe they might call that the C0.1 charge/discharge rate. Where very low ESR batteries might be C5, C10 or C20

---

I did not follow up on the changes other than my comment above which were listed as follows;

> 25 Change to Table 16 in 7.5.1.4 Rationale: The 0.2 ItA cycle life check every 50 cycles should be

> 26 eliminated since it can lead to misleading accelerated cycle life test results. Test termination at

> 27 60% capacity at 0.5 ItA more accurately reflects the actual usage conditions of most consumer

> 28 devices.

Comment: My initial understanding was different strategies of charging hugely affect the life of the battery. While there's some truth in it, as pointed out by other threads on this topic, this particular set of numbers (600 vs 2100 charge cycles) is merely the result of two different testing strategies, as you have pointed out.

Answer (score 2):

The sample [here](https://cdn.standards.iteh.ai/samples/74229/ce44583b604b40b0ac7c64730c20b3ed/SIST-EN-61951-2-2017-oprA1-2022.pdf) shows the section 7.5.1.4 in the IEC 61951-2 2017 standard:

For cycles 1-49 in a 50-cycle loop, the discharge current is now \$0.5 I_tA\$, whereas it was \$0.25 I_tA\$ in the 2011 IEC standard.

Additionally, IEC 61951-2 2011 stipulated that for cycles 1-48 in a 50-cycle loop, the discharge ends after 2 hours 20 minutes at \$0.25 I_tA\$.

In the previous standard the cell was only about 60% discharged (\$0.25 \cdot \frac{7}{3} \cdot 100\% = 58.\overline{3} \%\$ depth of discharge, leaving ~\$40\%\$ of cell capacity) whereas in IEC 61951-2 2017 the cell is discharged to \$1.0\space V\$, at which point the cell is almost fully discharged. Deeper depths of discharge can dramatically shorten the lifespan of a cell.

Panasonic Japan has an explanation on the topic here: [https://jpn.faq.panasonic.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/18109/~/%E5%85%85%E9%9B%BB%E6%B1%A0%E3%81%AE%E3%80%8C%E3%81%8F%E3%82%8A%E8%BF%94%E3%81%97%E4%BD%BF%E3%81%88%E3%82%8B%E5%9B%9E%E6%95%B0%E3%80%8D%E3%81%A8%E3%81%AF%EF%BC%9F-pz18109](https://jpn.faq.panasonic.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/18109/%7E/%E5%85%85%E9%9B%BB%E6%B1%A0%E3%81%AE%E3%80%8C%E3%81%8F%E3%82%8A%E8%BF%94%E3%81%97%E4%BD%BF%E3%81%88%E3%82%8B%E5%9B%9E%E6%95%B0%E3%80%8D%E3%81%A8%E3%81%AF%EF%BC%9F-pz18109).

> 【「くり返し回数」とは】
> JIS規格（日本産業規格）で定められた試験条件のもとで当社が試験した結果で、電池の定格容量（公称容量）の100パーセント放電し、充電と放電のくり返しが可能な回数のことです。
> 2019年3月JIS規格改定に伴いニッケル水素電池のくり返し回数の表記内容が変更になりました。
> ※JISの変更は、くり返し回数の測定条件が変わるだけで、電池そのものの性能が変わる訳ではありません。
>
> 【旧規格】　電池の定格容量（公称容量）の約60パーセントに低下するまでに、充電と放電のくり返し可能な回数。
>
> 【新規格】　電池の定格容量（公称容量）の約100パーセント放電し、充電と放電のくり返し可能な回数。
>
> ※詳細はJIS C 8708　2019  (7.5.1.4)  を確認ください。

DeepL translation:

> What is "Repeat Count"? The number of times a battery can be discharged to 100% of its rated capacity (nominal capacity) and charged and discharged repeatedly, as tested by our company under the test conditions specified by JIS (Japanese Industrial Standards). The description of the number of times a nickel-metal hydride battery can be repeated has been changed in accordance with the revision of the JIS standard in March 2019. The JIS change only changes the measurement conditions for the number of cycles, not the performance of the battery itself.
>
> Old standard:　The number of times a battery can be repeatedly charged and discharged before it drops to approximately 60% of its rated capacity (nominal capacity).
>
> New Standard: The number of times a battery can be repeatedly charged and discharged after it has been discharged to approximately 100% of its rated capacity (nominal capacity). *NOTE: test endpoint is also 60% of its rated capacity*
>
> ※ For details, please refer to JIS C 8708 2019 (7.5.1.4).

JIS C 8708:2019 seems to be equivalent to IEC 61951-2 2017, and JIS C 8708:2013 seems to be equivalent to IEC 61951-2 2011.